# What does the following mean with respect to, bitwise operations in C programming?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, enumeration

A book on C programming states,

```
enum corvid { magpie , raven , jay , chough , corvid_num , };
# define FLOCK_MAGPIE 1 U
# define FLOCK_RAVEN 2 U
# define FLOCK_JAY 4 U
# define FLOCK_CHOUGH 8 U
# define FLOCK_EMPTY 0 U
# define FLOCK_FULL 15 U
int main ( void ) {
unsigned flock = FLOCK_EMPTY ;
if ( something ) flock |= FLOCK_JAY ;
...
if ( flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH )
do_something_chough_specific ( flock ) ;
```

> Here the constants for each type of corvid are a power of two, and so they have exactly one
> bit set in their binary representation. Membership in a flock can then be handled through
> the operators: |= adds a corvid to flock, and & with one of the constants tests whether a
> particular corvid is present

Question 1. What is the code doing? What's the purpose of declaring enum corvid?

Question 2. What does "Here the constants for each type of corvid are a power of two, and so they have exactly one
bit set in their binary representation." mean?

Comment: Technically, the definition of `enum corvid` is not related to the defined macros at all.

Comment: `1 U` and the other such “numbers” will not compile. In C, `1U` is an `unsigned int` constant with value 1, but `1 U` will just generate a syntax error when used in an expression. Show the **exact** code used in the book.

Answer (score 2):

It becomes more obvious further down in the same text. The defines from your example are "hard-coded" (absolute values) constants used for bit masking. `something & 1U` gives the first bit in a chunk of data, `& 2U` gives the 2nd bit, `& 4U` gives the 3rd bit and so on.

The book writes them with decimal notation for some reason, but it is custom to write bitmasks with hex notation, because that's what they really are and it's the form easiest to understand. `something & 0xFU` masks out the 4 lowest bits, for example.

Now further down in the same chapter, the book swaps the hard coded constants for computed ones based on the enum. `#define FLOCK_MAGPIE (1U << magpie )` and so on. The advantage of this is that the enum can be modified and then the bit masks will get updated accordingly. Defines using shift like this is perhaps the most common form to define bit masks, with `1U << n` giving bit number n. Note that the first bit in any binary is called bit 0, so `1U << 0` gives the first bit.

Also note that all these expressions are *integer constant expressions*, meaning they are calculated at compile-time and gets replaced by a constant in your executable, so that your program doesn't need to calculate them in run-time.

Comment: if ( something ) flock |= FLOCK_JAY ;  " adds a corvid to flock but why not use assignment operator for that, flock = FLOCK_JAY. Also, in if ( flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH ), is flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH gonna yield a bool type value here?

Comment: @dexter an assignment would change all the other bits as well. OR'ing it will only set single bit(s) and leave the others unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

For question 2:

Since each number in the enum is a power of 2, there is only one bit set in its binary representation. For example `2 = 00000010` and `16 = 00010000`.

Comment: still not understood.

Comment: @dexter, take pencil and paper and write the numbers from 1 to 16 in binary, count the numbers of 1s in those numbers that are a power of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ...).

Comment: @David Ranieri, i got that but my question being, how is each no. in enum a power of 2? Check the code.

Comment: In the `enum` they are not a power of 2 but sequential numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... to be a power of two the `enum` must be defined as `enum corvid { magpie = 1, raven = 2, jay = 4, chough = 8, corvid_num = 16, };`, what makes them a power of two, as stated in another answer, is something like `#define FLOCK_MAGPIE (1U << magpie ) `