# What does the following mean with respect to, bitwise operations in C?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

A book on C programming states,

```
 enum corvid { magpie , raven , jay , chough , corvid_num , };
# define FLOCK_MAGPIE 1 U
# define FLOCK_RAVEN 2 U
# define FLOCK_JAY 4 U
# define FLOCK_CHOUGH 8 U
# define FLOCK_EMPTY 0 U
# define FLOCK_FULL 15 U
int main ( void ) {
unsigned flock = FLOCK_EMPTY ;
if ( something ) flock |= FLOCK_JAY ;
...
if ( flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH )
do_something_chough_specific ( flock ) ;
```

> Here the constants for each type of corvid are a power of two, and so they have exactly one
> bit set in their binary representation. Membership in a flock can then be handled through
> the operators: |= adds a corvid to flock, and & with one of the constants tests whether a
> particular corvid is present

Question.  "if ( something ) flock |= FLOCK_JAY ; " adds a corvid to flock but why not use assignment operator for that or "flock = FLOCK_JAY".

Also, is "if ( flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH )" gonna yield a bool type value?

Comment: `flock = FLOCK_JAY` will *replace* the current value of `flock`. If `flock` already had a value then that would be lost with the plain assignment.

Comment: The result of `flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH` will be an `unsigned` type (since that's what `flock` is). But you have to remember that in C and non-zero value is considered "true".

Comment: Read up on the concept of a "bit mask" - that's what happening... each bit in a number corresponds to a bird. `if ( flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH )` implicitly converts to `if ((flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH) != 0)` so yes, this yields a boolean expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70179130/what-does-the-following-mean-with-respect-to-bitwise-operations-in-c-programmin

Comment: @Some programmer dude but leads to the same outcome, or is there a benefit of using bitwise assignment here?

Comment: @dexter It only works for that specific case, where it's the *first* one.

Comment: @MortenJensen That's a misleading comment. There's no implicit conversion and your two examples are different. The `!=` operator is guaranteed to return 1 or 0, but the `&` operator might yield any non-zero value, possibly larger than 1. Thus `if (x = flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH )` and `if (x = (flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH) != 0)` can result in different values of `x`.

Comment: `1 U` and the other such “numbers” will not compile. In C, `1U` is an `unsigned int` constant with value 1, but `1 U` will just generate a syntax error when used in an expression. Show the **exact** code used in the book.

Comment: @Lundin the two if statements I wrote are semantically equivalent w.r.t. control-flow. I have no idea what you're getting at with the assignment to x - there are no assignments in the question or my comment?

Comment: @MortenJensen If thinking they are equivalent or boolean expressions, someone could get the idea to type `(flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH) == true` which is a bug.

Comment: @Lundin You're criticizing an assertion I did not make :)

Comment: @MortenJensen You said that `( flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH )` implicitly converts to a boolean expression.

Comment: @Lundin Nope. I wrote that `if ( flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH )` implicitly converts to `if ((flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH) != 0)` which makes all the difference. The part about a boolean expression was a quick attempt to answers OPs last question in a comment :)

Comment: IMO, this is close enough to your prior question to count as a duplicate, even if the sub-questions vary. [What does the following mean with respect to, bitwise operations in C programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70179130/what-does-the-following-mean-with-respect-to-bitwise-operations-in-c-programmin)

Answer (score 3):

> Question. "if ( something ) flock |= FLOCK_JAY ; " adds a corvid to flock but why not use assignment operator for that or "flock = FLOCK_JAY".

`|=` is used whenever one wants to preserve the other bits already set inside the variable. In this specific case it doesn't matter if `=` or `|=` is set since `flock` has the value zero.

> Also, is "if ( flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH )" gonna yield a bool type value?

It will yield an `unsigned int` since both operands are of that type. It will hold a value which is either zero or non-zero. This can be regarded as equivalent to a boolean condition though. It will only get bool type if you explicitly do `bool b = flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH;`.

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Assigning instead of ORing would knock out other bird types.  Say

```
flock = FLOCK_MAGPIE;
```

If you set

```
flock = FLOCK_JAY;
```

there would be no magipies in the flock but if you

```
flock |= FLOCK_JAY;
```

the flock would contain both jays and magpies.

Q2: The condition in the if statement doesn't yield a bool.  Any non-zero value is true.  A zero value is false.  If you want a boolean value, try

```
if ((flock & FLOCK_CHOUGH) != 0)
```